# Let $A$ belongs to $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $A^2$=$-I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ belongs to $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $A^2$=$-I$ then

a. $ n$ is even

b.  $A$=$\pm I$

c.  all eigen value of $A$ are real

d. $A$ is a diagolal matrix

My thought: $b$ is not true since $A^2$=$-I$

$c$ is not true since if $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ then $\lambda ^2$ is an eigen value of $A^2$ .here $\lambda ^2$=$-1$.

$d$ is also not true because $A^2$=$-I$

I have no idea about option $a$.somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

For part A, consider the following:

$$\det(A^2) = \det(A)\det(A) = \det(-I)$$

In particular, note that $\det(-I)$ cannot be negative.

Comment: I can not understand what you are trying to say.can you please explain?

Comment: Here's a little more: The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal entries.  Also, I'm applying the fact that, in general, $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: so what is the relation between det($A^2$) and n is even?

Comment: Well, we know that the left side needs to be positive since $\det(A^2) = (\det(A))^2$.  We also know that the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal entries.  Write out what we have so far on paper, and I think it'll become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Check the determinant of both sides of $A^2=-I$.